# Deploying a .Net application built in VSTS to a remote agent machine

Tags: automation, azure-devops

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days to no avail.

I have an MVC .Net Application that is stored in a GIT repo in VSTS. When I check in code it is being built and unit testa are being run in the cloud.

Now If these unit tests succeed I would like the project to be deployed to a remote machine that has the VSTS agent installed. I can see the agent in the VSTS web interface but I don't know how I get the automatic build to send the completed build to d:/mydeploypath on the remote agent machine.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely possible!

There are build steps available to copy files to a remote machine such as `Copy Files over SSH` and `Windows Machine File Copy`. But if you are trying to deploy the code to the machine you are building on, you can use the `Copy Files` step since it won't require credentials. Since it is a web application, there are a few steps like `IIS Utilities` to stop\start the application pool so the files won't be locked for the deployment.

So using the `Copy Files` build step, you could use `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` as the source directory (or wherever you have your build output going) and set the target folder to your desired destination on the machine.

The build/release variables helped me out a lot during the development of our release process: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts

Comment: Could you specify how to use the windows machine file copy. If I add that task to the build I only see target paths local to my Git repo, and If I add it in a later step based on the agent that only shows things local to the agent.

Comment: The file dialogues available in these steps are typically limited to the directory the build agent is using. Typically they won't show other directories. I think this is by design, but the agent can still copy files to the desired directory even if the dialogue isn't showing them. The path just needs to be typed in manually.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is using [WinRM-IIS Web App Deployment task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploy/README_IISAppDeploy.md).

To generate the web deployment package, you can specify these arguments in MSBuild Arguments box of Visual Studio Build task:

`/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" /P:PackageTempRootDir=""`